# I am using Kivy in Python and only the last button has it's embedded objects appearing

Tags: python, kivy

I apologize in advance if my question is stupid or obvious, but I have been researching this over and over and am coming up with nothing. I am currently using Kivy and have multiple buttons in a gridlayout, which is in a scrollview. Withing these buttons I have  a label and an image. Only the last of my buttons shows the label and image whenever I run my code. I think it has something to do with the positions, but I can't figure out what it is. Here is my code:

```
    Window.clearcolor = (0.937, 0.698, 0.176, 1)

class Solis(App):
    def build(self):
        b1 = Button(text= "",
                      background_color=(237, 157, 59, 1),
                      size_hint_y= None,
                      background_normal = '',
                      valign = 'middle',


                  font_size=20)

    lab1 = Label(text= Content1,
                color= (0.937,  0.698, 0.176, 1),
                valign= 'middle',
                pos=(b1.x , b1.height / 2))

    b1I = AsyncImage(source = lead1image)

    def callback1(self):
        webbrowser.open(lead1)

    b1.bind(on_press=callback1)

    b2 = Button(text= "",
                  background_color=(237, 157, 59, 1),
                  size_hint_y= None,
                  background_normal = '',
                  valign = 'middle',

                  font_size=20)

    lab2 = Label(text= Content2,
                color= (0.937, 0.698, 0.176, 1),
                valign= 'middle',
                halign= 'center',
                pos=(b2.x + 800, b2.height))

    b2I = AsyncImage(source = lead2image)

    def callback2(self):
        webbrowser.open(lead2)

    b2.bind(on_press=callback2)

    b3 = Button(text= "",
                  background_color=(237, 157, 59, 1),
                  size_hint_y= None,
                  background_normal = '',
                  valign = 'middle',

                  font_size=20)

    lab3 = Label(text= Content3,
                color= (0.937, 0.698, 0.176, 1),
                valign= 'middle',
                pos=(b3.x + 800, b3.height / 4))

    b3I = AsyncImage(source = lead3image)

    def callback3(self):
        webbrowser.open(lead3)

    b3.bind(on_press=callback3)




    l = GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=10, size_hint_y=None, orientation = 'vertical')

    l.bind(minimum_height=l.setter('height'))

    s = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, None), size=(Window.width, Window.height))

    s.add_widget(l)
    l.add_widget(b1)
    l.add_widget(b2)
    l.add_widget(b3)
    b1.add_widget(b1I)
    b1.add_widget(lab1)
    b2.add_widget(b2I)
    b2.add_widget(lab2)
    b3.add_widget(b3I)
    b3.add_widget(lab3)


    return s



if __name__ == "__main__":
    Solis().run()
```

And here is my result [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMkTi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something that should help you get what you want:

A main.py like this:

```
from kivy.app import App
import webbrowser

class Solis(App):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Solis, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.lead1image='https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/562300519008333825/6WcGRXLU.png'
        self.lead2image='https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/439154912719413248/pUBY5pVj.png'
        self.lead3image='https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/424495004/GuidoAvatar.jpg'

    def callback(self,url):
        webbrowser.open(url)

 if __name__ == '__main__':
    Solis().run()
```

And a solis.kv like this:

```
ScrollView:

    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        size_hint_y:None
        height: self.minimum_height

        Button:
            size_hint_y: None
            height:'50dp'
            on_press: app.callback(app.lead1image)

            AsyncImage:
                id:im1
                size_hint: None, None
                height: self.parent.height
                width: '48dp'
                source: app.lead1image
                pos: (self.parent.x, self.parent.y)

            Label:
                size_hint: None, None
                height:self.parent.height
                width: self.parent.width - im1.width
                text: 'Text for the 1st Label'
                pos: (self.parent.x, self.parent.y)

        Button:         
            size_hint_y: None
            height:'50dp'
            on_press: app.callback(app.lead2image)

            AsyncImage:
                size_hint: None, None
                height: self.parent.height
                width: '48dp'
                source: app.lead2image
                pos: (self.parent.x, self.parent.y)

            Label:
                size_hint: None, None
                height:self.parent.height
                width: self.parent.width - im1.width
                text: 'Text for the 2st Label'
                pos: (self.parent.x, self.parent.y)

        Button:
            size_hint_y: None
            height:'50dp'
            on_press: app.callback(app.lead3image)

            AsyncImage:
                size_hint: None, None
                height: self.parent.height
                width: '48dp'
                source: app.lead3image
                pos: (self.parent.x, self.parent.y)

            Label:
                size_hint: None, None
                height:self.parent.height
                width: self.parent.width - im1.width
                text: 'Text for the 2st Label'
                pos: (self.parent.x, self.parent.y)
```

Thus, there is now two files (a ".py" and a ".kv"): This will help you separate the logic of your application from its User Interface. Note that it is possible to reduce the length of the code with some customized widgets. Also, if you want to keep juste one .py file, I would add a "for" loop.
Finally, regarding your issue: I guess your labels and images were superimposed. I avoided this by using "pos:".